# How can I focus on next input when the first input value length is 3?

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I'm using formik and I have 2 input Fields .

```
const initialValues = {
  name: '',
  other: ''
};

<Formik initialValues={initialValues}>
  <Form>
    <Field name="name" />
    <Field name="other" />
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

What I want to achieve is when the length of the value in the name Field is 3 , the Field named as other gets focus on .

How can I write a function for name field value length is 3 then focus on the other field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get ref of `other` field

--Edit

[I see Field doesn't have onChange prop, but there is component which allows you to render specific input and attach onChange handler there](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field)

Looks terrible though

```
const otherRef = useRef(null);
// or this.otherRef = React.createRef(null)

const onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
  if(value.length > 3) {
    otherRef.current.focus() // ideally you'd check before if otherRef is defined
  }
}

<Field onChange={onChange} name="name"
  component={({field: {onChange: onFormikChange, ...rest}, form, ...props}) => 
    <input {...rest} {...props} onChange={(event) => {onFormikChange(event);onChange(event)}} type="text"/>}
/>
<Field name="other"
  component={({field: {onChange: onFormikChange, ...rest}, form, ...props}) => 
    <input {...rest} {...props} ref={otherRef} onChange={(event) => {onFormikChange(event);onChange(event)}} type="text"/>}
/>
```

Comment: Updated answer. Looks like any interaction with `Field`  component is very limited and you have to render custom component. Im not sure if `other` field needs such customization as there is some [innerRef](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#innerref) prop which you can use